# variables that can store vulgar fractions in c, or another approach to a code that solve systems of equations

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, matrix

I am a first year computer engineering student trying to make a calculator that solves systems of equations with multiple unknown variables using Gaussian-Jordan elimination

my algorithm is to put the equations in 2 dimensional array (matrix) and make the computer apply elementary operation rows by 
1- reorganizing the equations so the ones that starts with zeros be in the bottom
2- making all diagonal elements = 1 by dividing every row on the value of its diagonal element element11 element22 and so on
3- eliminating the elements up and down the diagonal to make an echelon form 
the answers should be the last column.
here is my code

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     int input;
     int rows;
      int columns;
     float matrix[100][100];
      int true =1;


  void interchange(curr,alter){
  float row_X[columns];
  float row_Y[columns];
  int k;
   for(k=0;k<columns;k++){
    row_X[k]=matrix[curr][k];
  }
 for(k=0;k<columns;k++){
    row_Y[k]=matrix[alter][k];
 }
 for(k=0;k<columns;k++){
    matrix[curr][k]=row_Y[k];
 }
 for(k=0;k<columns;k++){
    matrix[alter][k]=row_X[k];
}
}


void order(){
int e;
int count;
count = 1;
for(e=0;e<rows;e++){
if(matrix[e][e]==0){
    while(true==1){
        if(matrix[e+count][e]!=0){
                interchange(e,e+count);

        }
        count+=1;
        if(e+count==rows){
            break;
        }

    }
   }
   }
  }


void diagonals_to_ones(){
int g,h;
for(g=0;g<rows;g++){
        for(h=0;h<columns;h++){
            matrix[g][h]/=matrix[g][g];
        }
 }

 }


void zeros(){
int inverse;
int diag;
int i,j;
for(diag=0;diag<rows;diag++){
        order();
        diagonals_to_ones();
        for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
            if(i!=diag){
                inverse=-1*matrix[i][diag];
                for(j=0;j<columns;j++){
                    matrix[i][j]+=matrix[diag][j]*inverse;
                }
            }
        }

   }
   }

 void main(){
printf("Welcome to the awesome system of equations calculator,\n no need for 
 tedious elementary row operations any more,\n we do it for you, it's 
  computer era");
 printf("\n\n\nEnter the number of equations you want to solve (number of 
 variables) :");
 scanf("%d",&input);

 rows=input;
 columns=input+1;

printf("\n\nNow enter the cofactor of the variables\nfollowed by the free 
   nonvariable numbers for each equation\nin the same order");

 int a,b;
 for(a=0;a<rows;a++){
    printf("\n\n\n\nNow equation number %d",a+1);
    for(b=0;b<columns-1;b++){
        printf("\n\nEnter The Cofactor of Variable %d :",b+1);
        scanf("%f",&matrix[a][b]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter The free non Variable number :");
    scanf("%f",&matrix[a][b]);

  }

 printf("\n\n\nYour System of Equations is :\n\n");

 int c,d;
 for( c=0;c<rows;c++){
    for( d=0;d<columns;d++){
        printf("%.2f   ",matrix[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }


zeros();


for( c=0;c<rows;c++){
     for( d=0;d<columns;d++){
        printf("%.2f   ",matrix[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }




  }
```

***here is another version with a matrix ready for testing the answer should be 1,-1,2***

```
#include<stdio.h>
int input;
int rows=3;
int columns=4;
float matrix[3][4]={
{1,-2,3,9},
{-1,3,1,-2},
{2,-5,5,17}
};
int true =1;


void interchange(curr,alter){
float row_X[columns];
float row_Y[columns];
int k;
for(k=0;k<columns;k++){
    row_X[k]=matrix[curr][k];
}
for(k=0;k<columns;k++){
    row_Y[k]=matrix[alter][k];
}
for(k=0;k<columns;k++){
    matrix[curr][k]=row_Y[k];
 }
 for(k=0;k<columns;k++){
    matrix[alter][k]=row_X[k];
 }
 }


 void order(){
  int e;
  int count;
   count = 1;
   for(e=0;e<rows;e++){
  if(matrix[e][e]==0){
    while(true==1){
        if(matrix[e+count][e]!=0){
                interchange(e,e+count);

        }
        count+=1;
        if(e+count==rows){
            break;
        }

    }
  }
 }
 }


void diagonals_to_ones(){
int g,h;
for(g=0;g<rows;g++){
        for(h=0;h<columns;h++){
            matrix[g][h]/=matrix[g][g];
        }
 }

 }


void zeros(){
int inverse;
int diag;
int i,j;
for(diag=0;diag<rows;diag++){
        order();
        diagonals_to_ones();
        for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
            if(i!=diag){
                inverse=-1*matrix[i][diag];
                for(j=0;j<columns;j++){
                    matrix[i][j]+=matrix[diag][j]*inverse;
                }
            }
        }

     }
    }

 void main(){

printf("\n\n\nYour System of Equations is :\n\n");

int c,d;
for( c=0;c<rows;c++){
    for( d=0;d<columns;d++){
        printf("%.2f   ",matrix[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


zeros();

printf("\n\nthe answer is\n");

for( c=0;c<rows;c++){
    for( d=0;d<columns;d++){
        printf("%.2f   ",matrix[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }

printf("\n\nthe answer should have been\n");

float ansmatrix[3][4]={
{
1,0,0,1
},
{
0,1,0,-1
},
{
0,0,1,2
}

};
for( c=0;c<rows;c++){
    for( d=0;d<columns;d++){
        printf("%.2f   ",ansmatrix[c][d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
 }


 }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure about the algorithm and I doubt that it has to do with the way float handles fractions, I think that if there is a way to store fractions in common vulgar type the code will work right? or is it something else?

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: If you don't require the diagonal elements == 1, then you don't need to do arbitrary divisions, and you don't need to worry about storing fractions.  You can do the whole job with integers.

Comment: Unless you really don't care about exaggerating round-off errors, always use `double`, not `float`.  `float`  should only be used if storage is really restricted or you are working with an embedded CPU without native double-precision, and even in those cases only when you can live without computational accuracy.